# Добавление лишних картинок ListView

Tags: android, listview, java

в методе **getView**, проверяю условие и если оно верно, то вставляю в **item** картинку.

***Проблема:*** при первом запуске из 10 **item-ов** 2 удовлетворяют условие, всё нормально. в 2-х есть картинка.

Но при попытке пролистать список вниз и снова вверх, уже 4 **item-a** с картинками, даже те что не удовлетворяют условие, но, в **IF** те **item-ы** не проходят, получатся, картинка в них как то по другому попадает.
В итоге пару раз пролистав список, у меня все 10 **item-ов** c картинками.

```
if(row == null) {

        }else {
TextView days= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.days);
...
...
...
if (days == 0){             title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.star_big_on, 0, 0, 0);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (days == 0)
   title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.star_big_on, 0, 0, 0);
else
   title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

советую почитать про то, как работает ListView (в особенности уделить внимание кэшированию View)